# How delete list index position?

Tags: python, list

```
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

SO ,I want to delete any element of numList that is greater than 3,
but throws me an error. Any idea on this?

```
from datetime import datetime, date,timedelta
numList = [[2],[3],[4]]
for lst in numList:
for i in lst:
    if i > 3:
        print(i)
        del numList[i] # del numList[2] I dont want to use this 
                       #because numList elements are changing
        print("updated numList:",numList)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help u:

```
from datetime import datetime, date,timedelta
import copy 
numList = [[2],[3],[4]]
numListcopy = copy.deepcopy(numList) #Take a copy of the original list
for lst in numListcopy: #Iterate over the copied list
    for i in lst:
        if i > 3:
            print(i)
            del numList[numList.index(lst)]
print("updated numList:",numList)
```

Output:

```
updated numList: [[2], [3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I can use this in list comprehension:

```
[y for x in numList for y in x if y < 3]
```

Will give another list of

```
[2,3]
```

Get it into a variable and then iterate over it. (enclose first y to [y] to get [[2],[3]])